# Data reshaping with R (maybe it's easy, maybe not)

Tags: r, reshape, tidyverse

I need to produce a table containing the variables in one and only specific format because it will be used as input for another program. To this end I am trying to reshape my data (using R, of course) that looks like this:

```
# A tibble: 185,754 x 4
   rowid `SMPDB ID` `HMDB ID`   `TRUE`
   <int> <chr>      <chr>       <lgl> 
 1     1 SMP00004   HMDB0006454 TRUE  
 2     2 SMP00004   HMDB0001451 TRUE  
 3     3 SMP00004   HMDB0000005 TRUE  
 4     4 SMP00005   HMDB0000142 TRUE  
 5     5 SMP00006   HMDB0000060 TRUE  
 6     6 SMP00008   HMDB0000060 TRUE  
 7     7 SMP00009   HMDB0001451 TRUE  
 8     8 SMP00011   HMDB0004249 TRUE  
 9     9 SMP00011   HMDB0003850 TRUE  
10    10 SMP00011   HMDB0006953 TRUE  
# ... with 185,744 more rows
```

There are different `SMPDB ID` for every `HMDB ID`,
and I will need something like:

```
SMPDB ID    HMDB IDs
HMDB0006454 SMP00004, SMP00027, SMP00060, ...
HMDB0001451 SMP00004, SMP00008, SMP00090, ...
...
```

with only two columns, the first with the `SMPDB ID` and the other with all the `HMDB ID`.

Do you think it's possible to reshape it like this?

Perhaps starting with `spread`?

[Here](http://www.lucamassimino.com/temp/SMPDB_edit.tab.gz) the starting table if you wanna give it a try!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Should the column that contains the combined values of SMPDB for each HMDB ID be a list of the values or a character or...?  This may be a job for a group-summarize, first grouping by `HMDB ID` and then collapsing the `SMPDB ID` together for each HMDB.  Like `...%>% summarise(SMPDB = paste(SMPDB, collapse = ","))` (but with the actual column name).

Comment: That just worked!!